# C# Shuffle with Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I have been tasked with creating a shuffle method that takes an argument for how many times to shuffle, but for each shuffle, 1) Splits the deck(array) in half, and 2) starting with the first deck, alternates cards between the two:

Example: Before Shuffle- AS, 2S, 3S, ..., QC, KC

After 1 shuffle:
 AD, AS, 2D, 2S, ..., KC, KH

After 20 shuffles:
3C, 5D, 7H, 9S, QC

This is my deck constructor:

```
class DeckOfCards  {
    private Card[] deck;  
    private int currentCard; 
    private const int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52; // constant number of Cards 
    private Random randomNumbers; 
    // constructor 
    public DeckOfCards() {
        string[] faces = { "A", "2", "3", "4",
                           "5", "6", "7", "8",
                           "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K" };

        string[] suits = { "S", "H", "D", "C" };

        deck = new Card[NUMBER_OF_CARDS]; 

        currentCard = 0; 
        randomNumbers = new Random(); 


        for (int count = 0; count < deck.Length; count++)
            deck[count] = new Card(faces[count % 13], suits[count / 13]);
         }
```

This is what I have so far in main:

```
class Program  {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int numShuffles = 0;
        DeckOfCards myDeck = new DeckOfCards();

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} "+" {1} "+" {2} "+" {3}", myDeck.DealCard(), myDeck.DealCard(), myDeck.DealCard(), myDeck.DealCard());
        } 
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("How Many Times Do You Want To Shuffle?");
        string index = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("You want to shuffle {0} times", index);
        Console.ReadLine();
        try {
            numShuffles = Convert.ToInt32(index);
            for (int i = 1; i <= numShuffles;  i++) {

              myDeck.Shuffle();
            }

        } catch (FormatException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Input string is not a sequence of digits.");

        } catch (OverflowException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("The number cannot fit in an Int32.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        } finally {
            if (numShuffles < Int32.MaxValue) {
                Console.WriteLine("Preparing to shuffle " + numShuffles + " times");
                Console.ReadLine();


                    Console.WriteLine("{0} "+" {1} "+" {2} "+" {3} "+" {4}", myDeck.DealCard(), myDeck.DealCard(), myDeck.DealCard(), myDeck.DealCard(),
                        myDeck.DealCard());
                        Console.ReadLine();



            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Input cannot be incremented beyond its current value");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    } 

}
```

}

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Where's your shuffle method?

Comment: Yep, it's well easy. Loop from 0 to HALF. Each loop take `i` and `i + HALF`, add them to a result list. Try it and come back if you get stuck

Comment: Or you could just convert [this javascript solution](http://jsfiddle.net/m38gb1nt/) I just made. Though I don't get the same result after 20 shuffles as you do, even if I switch to starting with the second half of the deck :/

Comment: This is extremely trivial as far as algorithms are concerned. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I haven't started my shuffle method yet. I wasn't sure what all I could do with arrays or if there was an easier way to go about it. I am going to try musefan's way.

Comment: public void Shuffle() {
            string[] deck1 = null;
            string[] deck2 = null;
            for (int i = 0; i <= deck.Length / 2; i++) {
                string str = deck1[i];
            for (int j = 0; j <= deck.Length; j++) {
                        string str2 = deck2[j];
                }


            }
            

            } Still getting errors. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple: construct new array, taking one card from position 0, second from N/2, third from 1, fourth from N/2+1, etc.

Comment: That's something different. I'll try that now.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I'm all set now